# to receive a monthly investment payment of $200 at 5.5% p.a simple interest, what would tom need to invest

Tags: calculus

To receive a monthly interest payment of $200 at 5.5% p.a simple interest, what would tom need to invest

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's $5.5\%$ a year, that wold be $\$2400$ a year.

$\frac{100\%}{5.5\%} • \$2400= \$43636.36$

Comment: i spelled would wrong

Comment: kill me now omg